# Is there a way of running Wordpress Firebase Live chat on localhost

Tags: wordpress, firebase, chat, live

I am running Wordpress on localhost and im trying to get Firebase live chat working, but im stuck at an error that says: permission_denied when I send a message. Could this error be because the website is not on the web?

Comment: You might want to [search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+permission_denied), and see if it results in relevant hits.